# How does Java Jaxb Unmarshaller handle the fragment xml - the partial reading and writing of xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="http://www.lin.com/">
    <name>basket1</name>
    <fruits id="1">
        <price>9.99</price>
        <n>Banana</n>
    </fruits>
    <fruits id="2">
        <price>19.99</price>
        <n>Apple</n>
    </fruits>
</Document>
```

I have entity classes:

```
package com.baeldung.springsoap.basket;

@XmlType(name = "Document", propOrder = {"name", "fruits"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Basket {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "fruits", required = true)
    private List<Fruit> fruits;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
        return fruits;
    }

    public void setFruits(List<Fruit> fruits) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }
}

@XmlType(propOrder = {"price", "name"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "n")
    String name;

    String price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

ObjectFactory.java is:

```
package com.baeldung.springsoap.basket;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Document_QNAME = new QName("http://www.lin.com/", "Document");

    public Fruit createFruit() {
        return new Fruit();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.lin.com/", name = "Document")
    public JAXBElement<Basket> createBasket(Basket value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Basket>(_Document_QNAME, Basket.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

package-info.java is:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.lin.com/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.baeldung.springsoap.basket;
```

Java unmarshal and marshal code:

```
    public static void run_fruit() {
        try {
            //jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Basket.class); // If I use Basket.class,  when unmarshal, it got error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.lin.com/", local:"Document"). Expected elements are (none)
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.baeldung.springsoap.basket"); //

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            JAXBElement<Basket> f = (JAXBElement<Basket>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("./basket_fruit.xml"));

            // get a piece of fruit info, will save to file later.
            Basket bb = f.getValue();
            Fruit fruit=bb.getFruits().get(0);

            Marshaller jaxbMarshallerFruit = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // save a piece of fruit info into file
            // in real scenario， we need get a fruit data from list, then save to db as row data.
            JAXBElement<Fruit> jaxbFruit= new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://www.lin.com/", "fruits"), Fruit.class,  fruit);
            jaxbMarshallerFruit.marshal(jaxbFruit, new File("./fruit_in_basket.xml"));

            // read fruit info from file, convert to java object.
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshallerFruit = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<Fruit> f_file = (JAXBElement<Fruit>) jaxbUnMarshallerFruit.unmarshal(new File("./fruit_in_basket.xml")); // this line will throw an exception.
            System.out.println(f_file);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This line will throw an exception.

```
JAXBElement<Fruit> f_file = (JAXBElement<Fruit>) jaxbUnMarshallerFruit.unmarshal(new File("./fruit_in_basket.xml"));
```

The exception detail is:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.lin.com/", local:"fruit"). Expected elements are <{http://www.lin.com/}Document>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at com.baeldung.springsoap.xxml.JaxbExampleBasket.run_fruit(JaxbExampleBasket.java:48)
    at com.baeldung.springsoap.xxml.JaxbExampleBasket.main(JaxbExampleBasket.java:21)
```

From the exception, I guess the Java `jaxbUnMarshaller` can't figure out the authentic generics class info. UnMarshaller can't only interpret Fruit class. How to fix it?

Another minor question is:

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Basket.class);
```

If I use `Basket.class`, when unmarshal, it will get an error:

`unexpected element (uri:"http://www.lin.com/", local:"Document"). Expected elements are (none)`

If I pass `"com.baeldung.springsoap.basket"`, it works. Why?

(I have searched for a while, but maybe I can't describe my question with accurate words, so I missed something. If possible, kindly provide some links to the answer.)

Comment: @bdoughan, Could you please give me help? Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `Fruit` class an `XMLRootElement` should eliminate the exception.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fruits")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"price", "name"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fruit {
....
```